Put android lib .jar online (Github)
I have several .jar libraries in my project.
I do not have access to the source code, only the .jar.
I would like to make the implementation of these files available via github.
At the moment:

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/sdkJarExample', include: ['*.jar'], exclude: [])


What I want:

implementation 'com.github.MyProfile:MyProject:SomeVersion'


How do I configure my repository so that this works? I tried creating a .pom file, but without much success.
I have already declared in the repositories:

maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

